# Pythonic way to handle lengthy variables for unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am creating unit tests for a python script that parses the stdout of a command line argument. I have a sample output that I would like to implement in my current test cases. The output that I am testing is roughly 150 lines in length. Currently, I have a in my setUp() method, I initialize a variable equal to these 150 lines of output. Below is an example:

```
class RefreshStatusTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.stdout = """ Found 11 Servers
        Searching for ServerA
        Connecting to ServerA

        Refresh Active                          : No
        Status of Refresh
        ---------------------------------
        Start time : 2017-01-01T15:00:00.000
        ... repeat for 150+ lines...
        """
    def refreshAll(self):
        cmdOutput = self.stdout.split('\n')            
        #parse output for Refresh Active
```

What is the Pythonic way to handle variables such as this in a unit test? Should I create a different file/module that contains these values as static variables? Should I leave it as is?

Comment: It might make the test more readable if you had e.g. `with open('expected.txt') as f: self.stdout = f.read()`.

Comment: I'd agree with @jonrsharpe.  Such lengthy stuff is best put into a special directory in your unit test directory and read from there during the unit test; typical names for such things are *resource* or *canned data* and often they are created using a special script.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments and opinions. I have created a resource directory in my unit testing directory and added these variables as files as you suggested. Thanks for your help!